# What is the reason for not being able to deduce array size from initializer-string in member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-strings, in-class-initialization

Consider the code:

```
struct Foo
{
    const char str[] = "test";
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

It fails to compile with both g++ and clang++, spitting out essentially

> > `error: array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer`

I understand that this is what the standard probably says, but is there any particular good reason why? Since we have a string literal it seems that the compiler should be able to deduce the size without any problem, similarly to the case when you simply declare an out-of-class `const` C-like null terminated string.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509876/why-the-compiler-cant-set-size-of-char-in-a-struct-member-like-it-do and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656941/why-i-cant-initialize-non-const-static-member-or-static-array-in-class

Comment: because `str` can be also initialized in the member-initialization-list of Foo's constructor, discarding the initializer from the in-class initializer

Comment: Discussion on a related issue: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/lzcGWLDHxr4/5z4ZEmCCzLMJ

Comment: @aruisdante thanks, you can mark it as a dupe, I wasn't able to find a dupe myself. Although only the first link is probably a dupe, with no accepted answer.

Comment: @PiotrS. you should post an answer as it now makes it clear!

Comment: @vsoftco That's why I linked them as related, rather than duplicates. Neither question/answer set fully describes the problem, but they're both important to understanding a possible answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason is that you always have the possibility to override an in-class initializer list in the constructor. So I guess that in the end, it could be very confusing.

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo() {} // str = "test\0";

   // Implementing this is easier if I can clearly see how big `str` is, 
   Foo() : str({'a','b', 'c', 'd'}) {} // str = "abcd0"
   const char str[] = "test";
};
```

Notice that replacing `const char` with `static constexpr char` works perfectly, and probably it is what you want anyway.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Is there any way of making this work pre C++11? Just using `static const` doesn't work.

Comment: @vsoftco [yes, it is possible in pre C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/864408b6b834e9bf)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments and as answered by @sbabbi, the answer lies in the details

**12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]**

> 8. In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or
>      base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the
>      case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor
>      has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of
>      an abstract class (10.4), then
>
>    - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a brace-or-equal-initializer , the entity is initialized as specified in
>        8.5;
>    - otherwise, if the entity is an anonymous union or a variant member (9.5), no initialization is performed;
>    - otherwise, the entity is default-initialized

**12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]**

> 9. If a given non-static data member has both a
>      brace-or-equal-initializer and a mem-initializer, the initialization
>      specified by the mem-initializer is performed, and the non-static data
>      member’s brace-or-equal-initializer is ignored. [ Example: Given
>
>    ```
>    struct A { 
>        int i = /∗ some integer expression with side effects ∗/ ; 
>        A(int arg) : i(arg) { } 
>        // ... 
>    };
>    ```
>
> the A(int) constructor will simply initialize i to the value of arg,
>   and the side effects in i’s brace-or equal-initializer will not take
>   place. — end example ]

So, if there is a non-deleting constructor, the brace-or-equal-initializer is ignored, and the constructor in-member initialization prevails. Thus, for array members for which the size is omitted, the expression becomes ill-formed. §12.6.2, item 9, makes it more explicit where we it specified that the r-value initializer expression is omitted if mem-initialization is performed by the constructor.

Also, the google group dicussion [Yet another inconsitent behavior in C++](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/lzcGWLDHxr4/5z4ZEmCCzLMJ), further elaborates and makes it more lucid. It extends the idea in explaining that brace-or-equal-initializer is a glorified way of an in-member initialization for cases where the in-member initialization for the member does not exist. As an example

```
struct Foo {
    int i[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
    int j;
    Foo(): j(0) {};
}
```

is equivalent to

```
struct Foo {
    int i[5];
    int j;
    Foo(): j(0), i{1,2,3,4,5} {};
}
```

but now we see that if the array size was omitted, the expression would be ill-formed.

But then saying that, the compiler could have supported the feature for cases when the member is not initialized by in-member constructor initialization but currently for the sake of uniformity, the standard like many other things, does not support this feature.

Comment: Interestingly, this suggests that the behaviour _could_ be allowed if every user-declared constructor is deleted, and the default constructor is implicitly generated.  Perhaps worth a proposal?

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler was allowed to support what you described, and the size of `str` was deduced to `5`,

```
Foo foo = {{"This is not a test"}};
```

will lead to undefined behavior.